# How do you generate an admin link with a key

Tags: magento

I'm trying to generate an admin link in magento. So I do this

```
Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => $v))
```

Link Generated looks similar to this which is correct. It's just that the key seems to be wrong is my guess. 
https://example.com/myadmin/index.php/sales_order/view/order_id/3622/key/4b612dc7bfb9bc59aea7e2f06a62135b

The link looks ok when generated but when i click on it, it keeps asking me to login. Then when I login it throws me back to the dashboard instead of that same url.  Is there anyway I can fix this?

Comment: "The link looks ok".  Does it?  I don't see a link in your question description.

Comment: Hi Alan, added the link generated example above